# UIButton title replacement with each press

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I would like to present to the user with each press of the button different letter from the ABC.

So when it first click on the application the user will see the letter A, then they will need to press the button and then they will see the letter B and so forth.

My challenge is how to replace the text of the title with each click on the button.
I wrote down some code, of two functions, if you will take a closer look you will see that `-(void)displayABC:(id)sender` is getting called each time so each time I getting the first member of the array, so first time the user see the letter A then it press on the button and she/he see the letter B which is the first member of the array, but each the same letter is been presented because each time, we loading the plist file and therefore we keep calling the first member of the array.

Any ideas how to solve it?

```
-(void)createLoginBioButton
{
    authButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [authButton setBounds:CGRectMake(300,300, 150, 150)];
    [authButton setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 240)];
    [self.view addSubview:authButton];
    [authButton setEnabled:true];
    [authButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [authButton setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:70]];
    [authButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(displayABC:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
 }

-(void)displayABC:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ABC" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *ABCArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    for (NSString *ABCValues in ABCArray){
        [authButton setTitle:ABCValues forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep a reference to the current letter index as an instance variable and increment that with each touch?

Psuedo code

```
@property NSArray *abcs;
@property int currentIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.abcs = //load it from the plist
  [self updateButtonText];
}

- (void)buttonTouched
{
  self.currentIndex++;

  if ( self.currentIndex >= self.abcs.count ) {
    self.currentIndex = 0;
  }
  [self updateButtonText];
}
- (void)updateButtonText
{
  [self.button setTitle:self.abcs[self.currentIndex] forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to put a static variable which keeps tracking index

```
-(void)createLoginBioButton
  {

    authButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [authButton setBounds:CGRectMake(300,300, 150, 150)];
    [authButton setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 240)];
    [self.view addSubview:authButton];
    [authButton setEnabled:true];
    [authButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [authButton setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:70]];
    [authButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayABC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
 }

-(void)displayABC:(id)sender
{

    static int index = 0;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ABC" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *ABCArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if(index < [ABCArray count])
        [authButton setTitle:[ABCArray objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    index++;


}
```

Comment: Mihir I am getting the same, it present the letter A then the letter afterwards but not moving forward.

Comment: your index count is increasing ? or it's not ... have you tried using above code ?